# What roomba script went after this question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> [Feeds has been sharing it's tequila with Community](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17150039#17150039)

[More Accurate Random in C [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210149/more-accurate-random-in-c) was deleted by Community.

> [image: deleted by community]

(Full size image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/akYIY.png )

I am curious as to what script deleted it. My answer was at +2/-0 and accepted (I lost 35 rep).  Those *should* have kept some of the roomba scripts away from it.

So, what change to roomba scripts was it that caused this question to be deleted?

Furthemore, this deletion doesn't show up in the 'recently deleted' 10k tools spot.  I know that self-deleted questions don't show up there, but again... this was Community that did it.

The current display shows:

> [image: Recent deleted posts]

Nothing to show what Community has done the few minutes ago.

Comment: +1 for relevant socks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No roomba script here.

The OP requested deletion of their user account; part of the deletion script deletes negatively scored posts of the OP.

Sorry you got caught in that.

Comment: Confused.  Are you saying that if the OP raises a flag, some script other than the Roomba overlooks the upvoted answer and deletes anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - no. OP requested an account deletion. A CM pressed a button. The script that deletes users also deletes their negatively scored posts.

Comment: Reminder to all: if an answer you've labored over is sitting below a downvoted, closed question... **Edit the question.** It may be deleted at any time without warning, either by users voting or automatically by various systems, until/unless it is fixed.

Comment: [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131666/165773): "When you delete an account, the account is anonymized... and only negatively-scored posts are deleted."

Comment: @Shog9 How about we start [notifying answerers that a question they've answered is in trouble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209096/162704) then?

Comment: @Shog9 how do you recommend that answerers track that, if the question wasn't downvoted or closed when they answered it?